# NumPy's savetxt does not export delimiter when defining fmt for each column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have an array called `final`, that gets saved to text with a header. The array is built with numpy.column_stack as follows:

```
numpy.column_stack((SampNo, dummy, data, data1))
```

When I use

```
numpy.savetxt(f, final, delimiter=',', fmt='%1.7f')
```

The text file is saved with the delimiter correctly. However, I need the first two columns to be string rather than float, and when I use:

```
numpy.savetxt(f, final, delimiter=',', fmt='%s %s %1.7f %1.7f')
```

...the comma delimiter no longer appears in the file.

Also, as an aside, I end up using `%1.7f` 8 times after the two `%s` options as there are 10 columns in total. Is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `np.savetxt` docstring:

```
fmt : str or sequence of strs, optional
    A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a
    multi-format string, e.g. 'Iteration %d -- %10.5f', in which
    case `delimiter` is ignored.
```

You need to manually specify the delimiter within your format if you use the multi-format string approach.

To your aside, you can multiply the string to avoid some cut and paste:

```
In [5]: "%s,%s" + ",%1.7f"*8
Out[5]: '%s,%s,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f,%1.7f'
```